Eigenvalue Relationships in the Standard $m$-Dimensional Representation of $sl_2$ Lie Algebra
I am delving into the representation theory of the $sl_2$ Lie algebra, particularly focusing on its standard $m$-dimensional representation. The $sl_2$ Lie algebra is defined by its three basis elements $H$, $X$, and $Y$:

$H = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{pmatrix}$
$X = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$
$Y = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$

There's a notable relationship among the eigenvalues, specifically, the eigenvalues of a linear combination $aH + bX + cY$ match the eigenvalues of $\sqrt{a^2 + bc}H$.
My question centers on whether this eigenvalue relationship extends to the standard $m$-dimensional representation of $sl_2$. That is, for a given dimension $m$, does the eigenvalue relationship for $a\pi_m(H) + b\pi_m(X) + c\pi_m(Y)$ align with the eigenvalues of $\sqrt{a^2 + bc} \pi_m(H)$, where $\pi_m$ denotes the standard representation of $sl_2$ in $m$ dimensions?

All of the standard irreps $V_n$ of $\mathfrak{sl}_2$ are symmetric powers of the standard representation $V_2$ of $\mathfrak{sl}_2$ (the two dimensional representation where $H, X, Y$ act by the matrices you've written). This means that if $aH + bX + cY$ has eigenbasis $v_1, v_2$ with eigenvalues $\lambda_1, \lambda_2$, then $\pi_n(aH + bX + cY)$ has eigenbasis consisting of degree $n - 1$ monomials in $v_1$ and $v_2$—we write these as $v_1^{m}v_2^{n - m - 1}$—with corresponding eigenvalues $m \lambda_1 + (n - m - 1)\lambda_2$. Using this formula, you will find that your proposed relationship always holds.

Thank you for your answer. As a beginner in representation theory, I'm not familiar with many examples. I wonder if the eigenvalue relationship I mentioned is applicable to representations of other Lie algebras as well?
